# How to connect to remote cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

In plugin head I'm connected to localhost

[image]

When I try to connect to another (http:://host_name:9200) cluster it gives me this "cluster health: not connected"
How do I connect to remote cluster?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using default Elasticsearch configuration.

By default, Elasticsearch binds to localhost only. You can check your config in `config/elasticsearch.yml`. Set `network.host` in elasticsearch.yml to bind your node to a hostname or ip address. Check this documentation for more details:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

Comment: I did this...but after that I can't even open plugin head

Comment: Any error message? If you are using Chrome, you can open Developer tools and check the console tab.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow CORS in elasticsearch.yml.
Try adding:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/" 
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

It should show you head UI. Please note that you'll need to fine tune this configuration for production usage.

Hope I have managed to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using elasticsearch-head you can add auth user and pass to the url, then use the hostname and port in the connection box.

So access the plugin with a url like:

```
file:///Users/foo/elasticsearch-head/index.html?auth_user=foo&auth_password=bar
```

The index.html has some javascript that uses these variables for auth.

Also your browser should allow CORS so use an extension.